# Adding CSS Link to HEAD directly after metatags using JavaScript in IE8

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8

I want to add a CSS link immediately after the meta tags on my web page. I have the following code so far:

```
var el_head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var css_path_str = 'http://fakedomain.com/my.css';

var ref_obj = document.createElement("link");
ref_obj.rel = "stylesheet";
ref_obj.type = "text/css";
ref_obj.media = "all";
ref_obj.href = css_path_str;

var el_head_meta = el_head.getElementsByTagName('meta');
if(el_head_meta && el_head_meta.length > 0)
{
    var el_collection_count_int = el_head_meta.length-1;
    var el_meta_last_obj = el_head_meta[el_collection_count_int];

    var elem_parent_dest_obj = el_meta_last_obj.parentNode;
    elem_parent_dest_obj.insertBefore(ref_obj, el_meta_last_obj.nextSibling);
}
```

It works perfectly on modern browsers, but it doesn't work on IE8 (Surprise, Surprise!).

When I run the code above on IE8, the browser appears to be 'loading' for like 20 or 30 seconds, and then it does nothing.

Any ideas how I can get this to work?

**NOTE**: Using IE8 on Windows 7 Virtual Machine from Modern.IE

**EDIT:**

After fiddling around with this, I found that the script actually does work. I seem to have had a problem with IE8 and it's less-than-ideal developer tools. Whenever you load the page first time, it shows the CSS is added in the right place. However, when you refresh the page you don't see anything anymore (I'm not even going to hazard a guess why this is happening). Fortunately, the CSS file is indeed loaded (as verified with some sample declarations I put in the file being loaded). The only way I found to deal with this is to go the address bar and press enter; when you do this you see the added link reference in the DOM inspector. So, I guess I'll be doing that whenever I'm doing any testing on IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is IE browser

```
 var ua = window.navigator.userAgent; 
var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE "); if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) // If Internet Explorer, return version number 
alert(parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf(".", msie))));
    InsertLinkTag();
    return false; 
}
```

And use this work around in IE. And Append your style.

```
     function InsertLinkTag() {
           var css = '** your complete CSS style**', head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0], style = document.createElement('style'); 
    style.type ='text/css';if(style.styleSheet){ style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
    }else{ 
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
} head.appendChild(style);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. Please see my edit above. This happened to be an issue with the IE8 browser developer tools.

Comment: How about adding link tag through innerHtml.... document. getElementsByTagName ("head").innerHTML = "<link href=' style.CSS' rel='stylesheet '/>";

Comment: The script works, I just discovered an annoying IE8 that I just have to work around. I'm not sure innerHTML will work in my case as I don't want to replace what's in the HEAD, just insert stuff where I need it. Thanks